# Why does my for loop print the list twice

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, slice

So this might be a really stupid question but i'm a beginner in python.
But why is my for loop being printed

```
def Read_and_Slice(filename = "INSR.txt"):
inf = open(filename)
data = inf.readlines()
inf.close()
newlines = []

for I in data[4::2]:
    line1= I.strip().replace(" ", "")
    newlines.append(line1)

print(newlines)

line = ""

for j in range(len(newlines)-1):
    line = newlines[j]+ newlines[j+1] + line

return line
```

Comment: It would help if you gave some sample input and output to show what the function is supposed to be doing, and what it's actually doing.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation in the presented code.
Do you print the *returned line* in the calling function?